# how to add tipbox when mouse hover on the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/multiple.html

is there a way to add a tipbox  when the mouse hover on the copied text.the tip box say"the text has been copied" thank you.

HTML:code

```
<body>
<div>
 <div class="example" "></div><div>copied text</div>
 <div class="example" "></div><div>copied text</div>
<div class="example" "></div><div>copied text</div>
<div class="example" "></div><div>copied text</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Usaing flash? wow, 1. SEO problem, 2. Not friendly on some mobiles and other devices like iPad etc...,3. Why out smart something that does not need to, people know hot to copy and paste its like one of the first lessons on computers.

Comment: in my opionion more than 70% of the people that surf around the internet do not know how to copy and paste properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

yeah it is:

```
clip.addEventListener('complete', run_my_tipbox);
```

this will call the function run_my_tipbox when the text has been copied to the clipboard :)

so you will do something like that:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var clip = null;

    function run_my_tipbox(){ alert('Text has been copied to the clipboard!'); }

    function init() {
        clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setHandCursor( true );

        clip.addEventListener('load', my_load);
        clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', my_mouse_over);
        clip.addEventListener('complete', run_my_tipbox);

        clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
    }

</script>
```

hopefully this makes it a bit more clear ;)

Comment: i sorry i am new to js. how to write the run_my_tipbox function.should i put the code in function init() {}.thank you

Comment: edited the answer, just take a look if you understand what i mean ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried your answer,but it doesn't work,http://down123.xxmn.com/test1.html

Answer (score 0):

this is a fully working html file.. you can look what it does, it's pretty simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de"> 
    <head> 
        <title>h4kr.com</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /> 
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            body {
                font-size: 62.5%;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            .error-msg {
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                color: #ffffff;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                background-color: #990000;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            textarea {
                width: 450px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid #669966;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            #output {
                height: 200px;
                width: 99%;
                border: 1px solid #669966;
                padding: 5px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            #outputContent {
                font-size: 13px;
            }
            button {
                width: 450px;
                height: 40px;
            }
            span.label {
                width: 140px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }
            span.hidden {
                display: none;
            }
            div#clipboardcontent{
                display:none;
            }
            div#copyclipboardsuccess{
                position: absolute;
                top: 400px;
                left: 20px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                background-color: #009900;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.5;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
            div#errormsg{
                position: absolute;
                top: 150px;
                left: 20px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                background-color: #990000;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.5;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
        </style>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( 'ZeroClipboard.swf' );
        var clip = null;

    function init() {
        clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setHandCursor( true );

        clip.addEventListener('load', function (client) {
        });

        clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function (client) {
            // update the text on mouse over
            clip.setText( document.getElementById('clipboardcontent').innerHTML );
        });

        clip.addEventListener('onComplete', function (client) {
            copyclipboardsuccess();
        });

        clip.glue( 'd_clip_button','d_clip_container');
    }

    function copyclipboardsuccess()
    {
        var o = document.getElementById('copyclipboardsuccess');
        if(o.style.display == 'none')
        {
            o.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(copyclipboardsuccess,1000);
        }
        else
        {
            o.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    function errormsg()
    {
        var o = document.getElementById('errormsg');
        if(o.style.display == 'none')
        {
            o.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(errormsg,2500);
        }
        else
        {
            o.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

     </script>

        </head> 
<body onload="init();">
<h1>h4kr.com</h1><div id="errormsg" style="display:none">Error!</div><div id="copyclipboardsuccess" style="display:none">Copied to clipboard!</div><form id="form_cid" method="POST" target="output"><h2>Input</h2><textarea id="input_list" name="input_list"></textarea><br/><button type="submit" value="go">Go</button></form>      <h2>Output</h2>
    <iframe src="about:blank" name="output" id="output"></iframe>
    <div id="d_clip_container" style="position:relative">

        <button id="d_clip_button">Copy to clipboard</button>
    </div>
    <div id="clipboardcontent"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to when the mouse hove on the copied text, then display a tip. like this http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html. could you use my html structure to do that. many thanks.i put the html code on my question

Comment: in your code i must click the copied text, then display the toolbox

Comment: in my code it does not matter if you click or hover it ..
it's just this line:
        clip.addEventListener('onComplete', function (client) {
            copyclipboardsuccess();
        });

Comment: your html structure is hard. if i want to hover, how to alter it. thank you

Comment: and i don't know what's the use of this function.clip.addEventListener('onComplete', function (client) { copyclipboardsuccess(); });

Comment: could you use my html structure to do that. many thanks.i put the html code on my question